# JQuery how to get the content of a meta value that can have two different names?

Tags: javascript, jquery, meta

Using JQuery I can get the contents of a meta with name `PageID` like this:

```
$("meta[name='PageID']").attr('content')
```

How about when the name can have two different values e.g. `PageID1` or `pageId2` then I'd like to do:

```
$("meta[name='PageID1' || name='PageId2']").attr('content')
```

but this doesn't work.

Comment: You're right. I had the chance to either edit or mark my question as duplicate. I chose to edit it and not let it be duplicate as I was interested to know how to solve it using a logical disjunction with JQuery. But you are correct in my original OP I need the case insensitiveness and this is answered in the referred question. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can select it like this: `$("meta[name='PageID1'],meta[name='PageId2']").attr('content')`

Comment: This works perfectly thanks!